# using an aggregate value along with non-agrregate values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to use the average value of the column 'sales' from a table called 'previous_target' and compare that value with the individual rows of the same column 'sales' of the same table .
I get the required result when I disable the SQL mode from only_full_group_by.
But i would like to know if there is a better way to write the code without disabling the full group by mode.
Here is an example SQL query.

```
select 
f.id,t.sale as previous_target, 
case
when t.sale > 1.25*(avg(t.sale)) then round((avg(t.sale)*1.1),2)
when t.sale < 0.9*(avg(t.sale)) then round((avg(t.sale)*0.9),2)
else
t.sale 
end 
as current_target from 
details f 
inner join prev_target t on f.l_number=t.l_number
inner join time_details ft on ft.id=f.id
```

note:if i add the line

```
group by f.id,f.l_number,t.sale
```

it just copies the same value onto the current_target column .

can anyone suggest a way to use the average of the sales column from the prev_target table and compare it with each row of the same table with the given conditions.
I hope I conveyed my requirement without causing much confusion.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Comparing to the average of *all* sales or sales per xxx?

Comment: Do you need average of all sales values from  prev_target table or average of sales values group by l_number?

Comment: Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.id, t.sale AS previous_target, 
CASE
    WHEN t.sale > 1.25*(a.sale) then round(((a.sale)*1.1),2)
    WHEN t.sale < 0.9*(a.sale) then round(((a.sale)*0.9),2)
ELSE
    t.sale 
END AS current_target 
FROM details f 
INNER JOIN prev_target t ON f.l_number = t.l_number
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT avg(t.sale) AS sale, t.l_number FROM prev_target t GROUP BY t.l_number
)AS a ON t.l_number = a.l_number
INNER JOIN time_details ft ON ft.id = f.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause would be best recommended here for aggregation. I have created [sample run](http://rextester.com/BOV90303) for you (ofcourse different data and columns) but you will get the gist.

```
create table sales(amount int);
insert into sales values(5);
insert into sales values(10);
insert into sales values(15);
insert into sales values(20);
insert into sales values(10);

select * from sales;

select avg(amount) average from sales;

select amount, case when amount >= (avg(amount) over (PARTITION BY 1)) then 'Good' else 'Bad' end as type from sales;
```

Result >>

[image]